# Form Closing Event in a Form which i have made my self

Tags: c#, winforms, events

In a windows application in visual studio 2010 c# i have the follow problem :

I am making a `static Form S1HiddenForm;` and then i use it to open an application like this :

```
Command("Something[AUTOEXEC=2]", S1HiddenForm);
```

which opens me an usual windows form. I want to make an event that when the user presses X then he will not let him close the window.

If i have a usual Form i knew i could make it like this

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            e.Cancel = true; //I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that.
        }
    }
```

using the event handler in the designer view.

But in this S1HiddenForm i cant do it. Any suggestions? It seems easy but i cant find anything useful.

Comment: Are you looking to attach a close handler for a form you have no designer for? and need to do it in code? "S1HiddenForm.close += Form1_FormClosing;"

Comment: @MarvinSmit Yes exactly, i need a closing handler. I do not know how i will do it, in my example i just said how i could do it if i had designer view for it. The code you wrote does not do anything when i press X

Comment: @Savior Can your try use win32 api.Find the X button win32 handle and handle the button event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with Delegates. For help check [Delegates Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

type **S1HiddenForm.FormClosing+=** and type TAB, write your custom code in the event.

are you looking for this...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        static Form2 f1=new Form2();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            f1.Show();
            f1.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(f1_FormClosing);
        }

        void f1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
            {
                e.Cancel = true; //I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate more? i use the code you said but dont know how to write the rest

Comment: your code is working standalone but does not really work with mine. I do not know probably because i bind my form with another program, there is a problem there